# some phenomenon regarding locally free sheaves on surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface. Let $F$ be a slope stable vector bundle ( w.r.to some ample divisor say $H$ on surface) of rank $r \geq 2$ on $X$. Then :

$(1)$ Let $s \in H^0(F)$ be non-zero such that it vanishes on a divisor $mH$ ( for postive $m$) of $X$. Can we say that
every other non-zero section(s) of $H^0(F)$ also vanishes on the same divisor $mH$?

$(2)$ If $(1)$ is true, then can we say that when a section $s$ vanishes on a divisor $mH$ then the vector bundle $E(-mH)$ has nonzero section which doesn't vanish on a divisor of the form $nH$ for some nonnegative $n$?

For simplicity I would like to understand the question $(1),(2)$ when $r=2$

Comment: 1 and 2 are obviously false: take $X=\Bbb P^2$ and $F=\mathcal{O}(1)$. What is the question you are really trying to ask here?

Comment: @KReiser, I will edit, I mean $F$ is of rank atleast $2$ (I am more interested when the rank is $2$.)

Comment: Take a direct sum, then. You will have a better chance getting help on your underlying question if your ask about it. Voted to close for lack of clarity.

Comment: @KReiser, again in my case the bundles are stable w.r.to some ample divisor on surface. I will edit it in my question.

Comment: There are several notions of divisor (Weil, Cartier etc.). I think it would be helpful if you were more specific in this regard. Also be more specific on the involved dimensions: in general for a section of a rank $r$ vector-bundle, the expected codimension of the zero locus of a section is $r$. The way you have formulated the question it is unclear if you are assuming the zero locus to have codimension 1 (in which case I would expect the general section to have codim 2 (for $r=2$) and thus not have the vanishing property)

Comment: @Ihl73, Since the surface is smooth ( there ia a one to one correspondence and hence we can just use divisor). When I said a section vanishes on a divisor then automatically its zero section has codimension $1$. My second question was regarding if a section vanishes on a divisor then can the zero locus of sections of $F(-D)$ can be anything other than codimension $2$?

Answer (score 5):

A simple counterexample to question 1 is the tangent bundle $F = T$ on the projective plane $X = \mathbb{P}^2$. Indeed,
$$
h^0(\mathbb{P}^2, T(-1)) = 3,
$$
so there are sections of $T$ which vanish on a hyperplane $H$. On the other hand, a general section of $T$ vanishes at 3 distinct points.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. If $s \in H^0(F)$  vanishes on a divisor, then can we say that the zero locus of all (including non-general ones)  sections of $H^0(F(-D))$ is codimension $2$?

Comment: No. For instance, take $F = T(1)$. Then many sections of $F$ (those that come from sections of $T$) vanish on lines, but some of sections of $F(-1) = T$ also vanish on lines.

Comment: then can we say that we can continue this process of tensoring by $-D$ and this process terminates? ..one can finally obtain $E=F(D_1-..-D_n)$ such that zero locus  of each non-zero section of of $E$ is of codimension $2$.

Comment: Of course, there is a maximal divisor in the zero set of a global section $s$ of a vector bundle $F$, and if $D_s$ is such a divisor then $s$ is induced by a section $\bar{s}$ of $F(-D_s)$ and $\bar{s}$ has the zero locus of codimension at least 2 (and it is exactly 2, if $X$ is a surface, or if $F$ has rank 2 and $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay).